# Selecting columns from 3D tensor according to a 1D tensor of indices (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, one-hot-encoding

I'm looking for a way in tensorflow to, given two inputs:

1. `input1`, a 3D tensor of shape `(batch_size, x, y)`
2. `input2`, a 1D tensor of shape `(batch_size,)` whose values are all in the range `[0, y - 1]` (inclusive).

**return a 2D tensor of shape `(batch_size, x)`** such that the `ith` element in the output is equal to the `input2[i]-th` column of the `ith` element in `input1`.

Example:
If `input1 = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]], [[9,10], [11,12]]]`
(so shape of `input1` is `(3, 2, 2)`)
and

`input2 = [0, 1, 1]`,
then the output I want is `[[1,3], [6,8], [10,12]]`.

Explanation: The 0th element in the output is `[1,3]` because the 0th element in `input2` is 0; so, it becomes the 0th column in the 0th element of `input1`. The last element in the output is `[6,8]`, because the last element in `input2` is 1; so, it becomes the 1st column in the last element of `input1`.

Attempts:

I tried using tf.one_hot to accomplish this, (`tf.reduce_sum(input1 * tf.one_hot(input2, y), 2)`) but Tensorflow became unhappy when doing the multiplication, saying "ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [3,2,2], [3,2]."

Any help would be super appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm a software engineer at Google and I'd like to include a screenshot of this question in a research paper we're writing, to showcase some representative questions about TensorFlow. If that's alright with you, could you release your question under a permissive license? A comment saying e.g. "I license this StackOverflow question under the Apache License 2.0" would be sufficient for us. Thanks, David

Comment: I license this StackOverflow question under the Apache License 2.0. Out of curiosity, could you drop a link to the paper when it's completed? Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The paper is now available at [https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09040](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09040). You can read more about TF-Coder [here](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/08/introducing-tensorflow-coder-tool.html), and you can use it yourself [on Colab here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/google-research/tensorflow-coder/blob/master/TF-Coder_Colab.ipynb#scrollTo=DCvkqaXs4fyU&line=1&uniqifier=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.map_fn()` to achieve it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input1 = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]], [[9,10], [11,12]]]
input2 = [0, 1, 1]

tf_input1 = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,2,2),dtype=tf.int32)
tf_input2 = tf.placeholder(shape=(None),dtype=tf.int32)

result = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0][:,x[1]], [tf_input1,tf_input2], dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session()as sess:
    result = sess.run(result,feed_dict={tf_input1:np.array(input1)
        ,tf_input2:np.array(input2)})
    print(result)

# print
[[ 1  3]
 [ 6  8]
 [10 12]]
```

**Edit**

`tf.map_fn()` is slow compared to the vectorized operation. I added a matrix multiplication operation.

```
# shape= (3,2,1)
result = tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(tf.one_hot(input2, 2),-1),tf.int32)
# shape= (3,2)
result = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf_input1, result))
```

Comment: How efficient is this? Is it as efficient as just doing matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Kevin I added it to the answer.